# jQuery Mobile changePage with direction

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to specify both the kind of changePage direction and the direction of that that changePage? Something like: `$.mobile.changePage("mySpecialPlace.html", {transition: "slideup"}, {direction: reverse});`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html

You were close, but check-out the documentation I linked-to above, it'll show you the exact structure of all the options you can specify for the `.changePage()` method.

```
$.mobile.changePage("mySpecialPlace.html", {
    transition : "slideup",
    reverse    : true        //notice options are passed via the same object
});
```